# Convert binary response to ASCII string

Tags: groovy, ascii, soapui

I use `SoapUI` to send a request to webservice and get response.
How could I convert this binary response convert to `ASCII` string with `Groovy` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What binary form takes your response? Is it `byte[]`? If so you can easily convert it to `String` with following constructor:

```
new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
```

An example you can try in groovyConsole:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset

byte[] response = "Some response".bytes

assert new String(response, Charset.forName("UTF-8")) == "Some response"
```

Comment: I see, but got following error:
`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script5.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class java.io.charset.Charset @ line 1, column 1. import java.io.charset.Charset ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class java.io.charset.Charset @ line 1, column 1. `

Comment: Check your import: the exception you pasted mentions about `java.io.charset.Charset`, the Charset used in this example is `java.nio.charset.Charset`

Comment: Btw, you can also try following constructor with `String charset` -> 


    `new String(byte[] bytes, String charset)`


Then it would like like this:


    `new String(response, "UTF-8")`


In plain Java you would have to catch checked exception, Groovy does it for you.

Comment: It executes successfully, I corred the script, but returns with the same output as the input. No conversion.

Comment: What is your input type? You've only mentioned that it is binary response. Maybe it is already translated to String? Can double-check?

Comment: I was thinking about object type you are handling in this script. What is its class? What kind of class represents this object in your code?

Comment: The input is XML signature, X509Data, but I don't know much about output.